# Smartwatch Application Deployment

Tags: java, eclipse, sony, sony-smartwatch

I am struggling to find any documentation or tutorial on how to deploy an application to the Sony Smartwatch (I'm attempting to deploy the open source "Eight Puzzle" application written by Sony which I have imported into Eclipse. I have a Samsung S3 connected to a Sony Smartwatch, upon compiling I get the following:

```
No Launcher activity found!
The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
Performing sync
Automatic Target Mode: using device '4df1e79d35975fa7'    
Uploading EightPuzzleExtension.apk onto device 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
Installing EightPuzzleExtension.apk...
Success!
\EightPuzzleExtension\bin\EightPuzzleExtension.apk installed on device
Done!
```

But after reinstalling Sony SmartConnect and looking through under "Applications" and "Sort Applications" on the device, I am unable to find the app. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- I just [downloaded](http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/code-example-module/music-player-and-8-game-extensions-for-smartwatch-open-source/) the open source code.
- Unzipped the files
- Imported the code into eclipse using File > Import.
- Added SmartExtensionAPI and SmartExtension Utils as Libraries into the
  Eight Puzzle Game project.
- Using Run > Configurations installed the application on my device
- Application installed
- Sort application screenshot shows the application at the bottom as 8 game.
- Also shows up on the smartwatch, I can post a pic if you need to verify

It shows up on the bottom of my screen. [image]

I am not sure about the issue you are facing. If you did the same procedure as mine, it should work the very first time.

Comment: I just checked with a Galaxy S3 to make sure it is not something with the device being different. It works there too! Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Thanks, I've solved the issue, turns out I was setting the libraries incorrectly and I had to restart eclipse several times to solve the issue.

Comment: +1 for `Added SmartExtensionAPI and SmartExtension Utils as Libraries` which may be most non-obvious thing here.

Comment: I have the same problem as original poster. I followed Anup instructions, but no luck. I wonder if I am adding libraries the proper way? I tried to add SmartExtensionAPI and SmartExtension Utils on two different ways: a)project->properties->java build path->projects tab->add b)project->properties->java build path->libraries->add jars (jars are generated in bin folder of SmartExtensionAPI and SmartExtension Utils when I check "isLibrary" flag under android section of project properties).I also get error in layout file where "@dimen/smart_watch_control_width" (as well as height) isnt recognized.

Comment: Hi @AidenThompson: I am having the same issue with sample application. I also checked if the libraries (SmartExtensionAPI, SmartExtensionUtils) are added properly. but application is not showing in the phone/watch. any other suggestions to solve this issue?